# grocery crud with AES Encryption

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

How to match data in table using mysql AES decrypt in grocery CRUD ?

**Error getting on crud set realtion as follows:**

```
$crud->set_relation(AES_DECRYPT(departments.department_id,'key'),'users.department_id','deparmtnet_name');
```

**Not Found: departments.AES_DECRYPT(departments.department_id,'key')**

```
select user_name,department_name from users as j333 left join departments jd333 on departments.AES_DECRYPT(departments.department_id,'key')=j333.department_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Grocery Crud doesn't recognize "AES Decrypt" function

Comment: Then how we implement this?